# Where can I find good Domain Driven Design resources?

Tags: domain-driven-design

What are the best places to find out everything there is to know about Domain-Driven Design, from beginner to advanced.

- Books
- Websites
- Mailing lists
- User groups
- Conferences
- etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some interesting sources:

- the [DDD](http://dddcommunity.org/books/index.html#DDD) book by Eric Evans
- the free [DDD Quickly](http://dddcommunity.org/books/index.html#DDD_quickly) book
- the [DDD newsgroup](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/)

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has some useful information, especially its summary of how DDD relates to other approaches.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

It also links to two presentations by Eric Evans

- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/model-to-work-evans
- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/strategic-design-evans

Answer (score 5):

This [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice) is a good introduction on how to do DDD in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe read the book [Domain Driven Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=domain+driven+design&pg=PP1&ots=ulAQZXV5q7&sig=rMvPNRKLH79CBuNOSH9wu4WzfiA&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=5&ct=result)?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend  [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) from Eric Evans, it's a great book on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some informative sources:

- An [interview](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2006-03/episode-8-interview-eric-evans) with Eric Evans on Software Engineering Radio
- A [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147563) which applies the principles of DDD using an example in C#
- A [podcast](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-25/) on Getting Started With Domain-Driven Design by Rob Conery
- A [conversation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast140RobConeryLearnsAboutDomainDrivenDesign.aspx) between Scott Hanselman and Rob Conery on Learning DDD.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, perhaps :) however, in case anyone is still interested, I found some very useful information and considerations on DDD on [Epic.NET project site](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/a_shared_modeling_grammar.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202) is a very good book on the subject. Lots of good examples as well as discussion of related subjects like test driven development and how they apply.

Also check out [domaindrivendesign.org](http://domaindrivendesign.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Casey Charlton has created a new DDD resource site at http://dddstepbystep.com/.  It is a great reference site and has lots of info for DDD newbies and experts alike.

Comment: http://dddstepbystep.com/. its on chinese language